# Remove brackets single quotation marks and periods from array using `Dir.entries(".")`

Tags: ruby

I am doing `Dir.entries('.') { |e| "<p>#{e}</p>" }`to output directories. However, it prints the entire array like it would in bash.

Example output: `[".", "..", "162001", "162002", "162003"]` etc

How can I alter the formula to remove the special characters and periods just leaving the text?

edit:

the example output i am trying to achieve is:
`162001` 
`162002`
`162003`
etc...

example of what I am getting currently on my html page and need to eliminate:
i just need to see the folder names, nothing else
[image]

Comment: You can't. The method does not take a block. It is also not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: updated post a bit, i need to remove the block characters, quotations, commas and dots from the output

Comment: You can try this ` Dir.entries('.') { |e| "<p>#{e}</p>" }.map{|a| a.gsub(/[^0-9A-Za-z]/, '')}.reject(&:blank?)`

Comment: So you want a string?

Comment: It's outputting that because you're not outputting anything. `entries` returns the entries--not a formatted string. Sounds more like you want the entries `join`ed in some meaningful way, apparently HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding, based in your example, you are referring `.` and `..` as "*special characters and periods*". These are Unix-like hidden files (dotfiles). If you want to list all files except hidden files, you can use this:

```
Dir.glob("*").map { |e| "<p>#{e}</p>" }
```

or for removing all special character named files:

```
Dir.entries('.').map { |e| "<p>#{e}</p>" if e.delete(' ') =~ /\w/ }.compact #using delete to remove spaces before regex
```

Here we are rejecting all filenames that contains any characters except letter, number and underscore.

To get String output in separate lines:

```
puts Dir.entries('.').map { |e| "<p>#{e}</p>" if e.delete(' ') =~ /\w/ }.compact.join("\n")
```

Comment: this got rid of all filenames with dots and special characters which is good, but i still need to eliminate the [ ], and ", " - i added an image for you to see what I am doing with it

Comment: @ADL `entries` just iterates--you're getting the array of names back. Use `join`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way

if you only want only directories of that directory

```
>> Dir.entries(".").select {|f| File.directory? f}
=> [".", "..", "api_product", "connection_pool", "factory_girl",
e_api", "todo"]
```

now remove all special char

```
>> Dir.entries(".").select {|f| File.directory? f}.join(" ").gsub!(/[^0-9A-Za-z]/, ' ').strip
=> "api product connection pool factory girl grape lonely lonely batch mysql2 postgres rails rubocop salesforceheroku salesforceheroku2 sidekiq simple api todo"
```

I think you want the below

```
 irb(main):064:0* Dir.entries(".").select {|f| File.directory? f}.join(" ").gsub!(/[^0-9A-Za-z]/, ' ').strip
=> "api product connection pool factory girl grape lonely lonely batch mysql2 postgres rails rubocop salesforceheroku salesforceheroku2 sidekiq simple api todo"
irb(main):065:0> Dir.entries(".").select {|f| File.directory? f}.join("  ").gsub!(/[^0-9A-Za-z]/, ' ').strip
=> "api product  connection pool  factory girl  grape  lonely  lonely batch  mysql2  postgres  rails  rubocop  salesforceheroku  salesforceheroku2  sidekiq  simple api  todo"
irb(main):066:0> Dir.entries(".").select {|f| File.directory? f}.join("  ").gsub!(/[^0-9A-Za-z]/, ' ').strip.split("  ")
=> ["api product", "connection pool", "factory girl", "grape", "lonely", "lonely batch", "mysql2", "postgres", "rails", "rubocop", "salesforceheroku", "salesforceheroku2", "sidekiq", "simple api", "to
do"]
irb(main):067:0> Dir.entries(".").select {|f| File.directory? f}.join("  ").gsub!(/[^0-9A-Za-z]/, ' ').strip.split("  ").map{|c| "<p>"+c+"</p>"}
=> ["<p>api product</p>", "<p>connection pool</p>", "<p>factory girl</p>", "<p>grape</p>", "<p>lonely</p>", "<p>lonely batch</p>", "<p>mysql2</p>", "<p>postgres</p>", "<p>rails</p>", "<p>rubocop</p>",
 "<p>salesforceheroku</p>", "<p>salesforceheroku2</p>", "<p>sidekiq</p>", "<p>simple api</p>", "<p>todo</p>"]
```

here I seperate two word by "  " double space(like after remove "_" from all api product and connection pool will be separated by double space so that I can map it with

and

)

```
Dir.entries(".").select {|f| File.directory? f}.join("  ").gsub!(/[^0-9A-Za-z]/, ' ').strip.split("  ").map{|c| "<p>"+c+"</p>"}
```

look `join` and `split` both has double space

Comment: This looks excellent, I need to add .map and <p></p> so each directory reports on its own line

Comment: added an image for more detail, unfortunately this didnt work =/

Comment: I am very confused my this one, it works perfectly if i use the directory "." but if i specify one directly it doesnt return anything